# Correct way to raise OnProgressChanged event from within BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I currently have a BackgroundWorker (BGW) that I use to output a series of reports. To do this I call RunWorkerAsync and pass through a couple of required parameters.

My question is, how can I raise the BGW's OnProgressChanged event from within the code running on the separate thread? My program outputs 18 reports, some of which take a while to execute and I'd like to update my UI with regular progress updates. Is this even the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for ReportProgress 
i made up a quick example (console application)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Percentage is:{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
        }

        static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            var self = (sender as BackgroundWorker);
            self.ReportProgress(10);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            self.ReportProgress(20);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            self.ReportProgress(30);
        }

    }
}
```

hope that covers your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was specifically concerned with how to raise the ProgressChangedEvent from within the code called by the RunWorkerAsync method (the DoWork method in your example). I've found that I can pass the BGW to the called code and call the ReportProgress without issue.